# Linking barcode scanner to MS Access, and update it in a real time

Tags: database, ms-access, barcode-scanner, inventory-management

I am trying to figure out how to connect/sync a barcode scanner to my microsoft access database. I have couple of wireless scanners which scan inventories in different places of a plant, and I want to see the scanned data at the real time in my database. Any tips how to do this?

Comment: Scanner = keyboard, there is no difference for application. Set focus in desired field and scan. Scanner can also add Enter after scan and you can enable special text codes (AIM code) before scanned data with scanned barcode type.

Comment: I should have cleared my question better;  I actually do not stand by scanners;  there are like 8 people who are scanning inventories in different locations of a plant, and I am gonna work on the database and want to see the data at the real time once transactions goes through in my database. The scanner supports wifi.  I am not sure if I need to program this setting in MS Access which is what I use.

Comment: I understand. First of all you need to connect scanners correctly, it's not related to Access at all. Even WiFi scanner is just a keyboard, which types symbols into control, which has focus. Task of system administrator - connect scanner, run application and give focus to the application. Task of Access developer - set focus to dedicated control (textbox I think) and receive input from scanner. If sysadmin give focus to Notepad, you will see the text from scanner in Notepad the same way.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "wireless scanners which scan inventories". Are these just barcode scanners (which as Sergey said, are just keyboards as far as Windows is concerned) or some kind of hand-held terminal with its own software that directly interacts with your Inventory database?

Comment: Yes, they are just barcode scanners